# MySQL UPDATE JOIN statement speed issues

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables in a MySQL database that I can't seem to work with very efficiently. The first is a payments table with around 25,000 rows and the following fields.

```
ID, Email, Type
```

The second is a users table which has 2,000 rows and the following:

```
ID, Email, AccessDate
```

Using the MySQL JOIN statement I have put this together, and it works perfectly:

> UPDATE users INNER JOIN payments ON users.Email=payments.Email SET
>   AccessDate=NOW() WHERE payments.Type='success'

The problem is, it takes about 95 seconds to execute the query on a local machine. Any tips on how I might get around this speed issue?

Comment: Add some indexes on your tables

Comment: can you post the results of `show index from table_name` for each of the two tables?

Comment: Apologies for my probable ignorance here, but does the ID field in each table not count as an index as it's also a primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you can use EXPLAIN to see what the optimiser is doing. You`ll have to reconstruct the code to be a SELECT:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN payments ON users.Email=payments.Email WHERE payments.Type='success'
```

Most likely is that the join has no index it can use. Does "ID" have an Index? Perhaps you can add that to the Join clauses? Or possibly add indexes for the "Email" column on both tables?

Comment: Yup! Added indexes to the Email column and it executes in well under half a second.... You're a star! Thanks Giles!